# IE8 showing red background in footer

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

[image: ie8 showing red background at social icons in the footer.]

I have tried deleting all `#f00` color and changed all the `background`s, but Internet Explorer is not showing social icons correctly. I have tested it in IE10 and all the major browsers, and this problem does not appear

Comment: We can't guess until you post the related code here. :)

Comment: Check background color for those elements, maybe something is passed from the parents :P

Comment: OK LET ME POST MY CONTENT

Comment: Are that PNG Icons? IE8 has a bug (or feature?) with transparent PNG Icons. Try to set a `background: tranparent !important;` directly to the Image-Element. Other possibility is, that you're using a CSS opacity on these elements. This could also be responsible for this behavior.

Comment: Long shot here, but perhaps IE8 needs its cache cleaned out, if you haven't done that? Pretty sure it's not this, but it never hurts to make sure you don't have out of date assets lying around.

Comment: Thanks Stefan Brendle... ie8 has issue with opacity on png's .. i was using opacity 0.8 on png.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a PNG with transparency, and combining it with a CSS opacity (that is, using IE's proprietary `filter` opacity), then you may be running into a known IE8 bug. See [hjere](http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/ie-transparency-problems/) for a discussion and some possible work-arounds.

Advice: don't use `filter` styles in old IE. There are a number of things that can't be done in IE8 or earlier without using `filter`, which means that `filter` is very tempting to use. But it has so many quirks and bugs that it is very rarely worthwhile. In many cases, the site is more usable in IE8 without them. If you need to use those features, it may be a good case for not supporting IE8 at all.

Also, I note from your screenshot that the page is loading in compatibility mode (see the 'broken page' icon in the address bar). This means that although you're using IE8, you're actually seeing it in IE7 mode (or possibly even quirks mode; it's hard to be certain from the screenshot, though I think IE7 mode is more likely). You should try to fix this problem as well, as there will be additional IE bugs and missing features that you'll be seeing as a result of using the wrong mode.

Answer (score -1):

Are that PNG Icons? IE8 has a bug (or feature?) with transparent PNG Icons. Try to set a background: tranparent !important; directly to the Image-Element. Other possibility is, that you're using a CSS opacity on these elements. This could also be responsible for this behavior.

thanks – Stefan Brendle

Comment: This is not the proper way to thank someone for helping you. Upvote their comment/answer instead of posting a separate answer